# Query results don't match NumFound when using SolrNet with VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, solr, solrnet

I have implemented SolrNet in a VB.NET web site and it's working perfectly with one exception. My results object may tell me that 10 matching "documents" have been found but the collection only contains 9.

My collection always contains 1 less than the NumFound property states. I have run the queries directly through my Solr instance and I know that the NumFound property is reflecting the correct value. Having reviewed the returned documents I can see that the first document in each result set is missing from my collection i.e. the one at position 0.

This seems like a problem connected to a zero indexed collection.

I can't see that I'm doing anything wrong and suspect that this is a bug. Has anyone else experienced this or can you suggest where I may have gone wrong?

Source code is as follows

```
Private Prods As New SolrQueryResults(Of BLL.solrProduct)

Dim solr As ISolrOperations(Of BLL.solrProduct) = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance(Of ISolrOperations(Of BLL.solrProduct))() 

Dim SolrQueryOptions As New SolrNet.Commands.Parameters.QueryOptions() With {.Stats = New StatsParameters(), .Start = PagingCurrent, .Rows = PagingSize, .Facet = New FacetParameters() With { _ 
.MinCount = 1, .Queries = New SolrNet.ISolrFacetQuery() {New SolrFacetFieldQuery("brand")}}}  

SolrQueryOptions.Stats.AddField("selling_price")

SolrQueryOptions.FilterQueries.Add(New SolrQueryByField("brand", "puma"))

Prods = solr.Query("shirt", SolrQueryOptions)

PagingTotal = Prods.NumFound    'This returns 10
lv_prods.DataSource = Prods
lv_prods.DataBind()             'This renders 9 items
```

Comment: Please post a failing test... without any more information all I can say is to use the sample app as reference. Also, why are there pipes in your category query?

Comment: The query string that I'm using on my Solr instance to mirror what I'm sending through the SolrNet library is as follows

Comment: q=product_name:shirt OR product_description:shirt OR id:shirt&start=0&rows=12&facet=on&facet.field=brand&fq=brand:puma&facet.mincount=1&stats=true&stats.field=selling_price

There are pipes in my category query as this is the way I have dealt with a product belonging to more than one category, the category field contains a pipe seperated list of all the categories a product belongs to and I can then issue a query against the category field like so "|8878|" to get all the products belonging to category 8878. The actual field contents could be "|8854|8896|8878|8564|"

Comment: use a multivalued field instead. I'll still need a failing test to diagnose your doc count issue...

Comment: I'm really sorry but I'm not sure specifically what you're looking for with the failing test? Do you need the actual source code that I'm using?

As for the multivalued field, I think that would work but I have Solr set up to index from SQL Server and off the top of my head I would have to mess about a lot with my source data to get this to index properly. I'll definitely look in to it though, thanks!

Comment: Sorry, can't do anything without some code. Take a look at the sample app for guidance.

Comment: If you can't share your code for some reason, you can hire me privately through oDesk https://www.odesk.com/users/~~d93a7b1e49b6d28f

Comment: please post the code as part of the question so it can be properly formatted.

Comment: I've edited the original post

Comment: Have you checked the `Count` property on `Prods`?

Comment: Yes. Prods.NumFound = 10 and Prods.Count = 9

Comment: Great, now what are the values of `PagingCurrent` and `PagingSize`?

Comment: PagingCurrent = 1 and PagingSize = 12

Comment: You mentioned before a Solr querystring with start=0. That corresponds to PagingCurrent=0, not 1. Also, does the result directly from Solr match the result you get from SolrNet?

Comment: That's got it! This is replacing an existing search system where the paging indexing starts at 1 so this was carried over. Many thanks for your help Mauricio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solr pagination is zero-based, i.e. the first item corresponds to Start=0